# Find middle value of a list

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm having trouble figuring out how to find the middle value in a list of double words that has an even amount of 50 numbers. When I try to implement my code as follows

```
mov eax, dword[volumes+100]
add eax, dword[volumes+104]
div dword[saTwo]
mov dword[vMid], eax
```

where volumes 100 and 104 are the 25th and 26th elements in the list. I then divide by two and store the middle value in vMid. The problem arises when I debug the program vMid is 0 which is definitely not correct.

Comment: although we can see it after we opened your question: please specify which kind of assembler you are talking about in the tags. I bet there is a x86 tag available and adding this one will certainly make the ARM guys happy ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Don't DIV. Use right shift instead.

If the numbers are unsigned, the carry flag contains the overflow, so use RCR.
Otherwise SAR. If speed is an issue, check combinations of clearing carry flag and RCR.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble likely has to do with `EDX` though you may not realize it at first. :)

In the x86 instruction set the size of the `DIV` is determined by the operands, as you would expect.  However, by specifying a 32 bit divide with your `DWORD PTR` the processor will automatically attempt to divide like so: `EDX:EAX / DWORD [saTwo]`.  `EAX` represents the least significant portion of the dividend.  If EDX happens to have a relatively large value in it then the resulting quotient will likely be zero with a remainder sitting in `EDX`.

You will want to clear `EDX` first and then perform your `DIV`